# What is - some : Error Domain=CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code=1005 "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I've tried to load icloud image using phasset with options
requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
I get CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code=1005 error I don't understand where I make mistake, I have used SDWebImagePhotosPlugin methods as well as Photos methods like requestImageDataAndOrientation and requestImageData, still I get the image as nil and the above error

this is my code:

```
imageManager.requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: deviceImage, options: phImageRequestOptions()) { data,deliveryMode, orentation, _ in
                if data != nil {
                    completion(data)
                } else {
                    SDImageLoadersManager.shared.loaders = [SDWebImageDownloader.shared, SDImagePhotosLoader.shared]
                    SDWebImageManager.defaultImageLoader = SDImageLoadersManager.shared
                    
                    let photosURL = NSURL.sd_URL(with: deviceImage)
                    SDImagePhotosLoader.shared.requestImage(with: photosURL as URL?, options: [.highPriority,.retryFailed,.refreshCached], context: [.customManager: self.manager], progress: nil) { image, data,error, success in
                        if image != nil {
                            completion(image?.pngData())
                        } else {
                            completion(nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **isNetworkAccessAllowed** to true?
options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

for iCloud images this option needs to be true.